# Home and end keys not working in kdenlive

Tags: kdenlive

i'm on kdenlive and for some reason the home and end keys aren't working ctrl+left or right takes me to the beginning or end of each clip but not home or end keys, i have no idea what's going on, any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [online documentation](https://userbase.kde.org/Kdenlive/Manual/Useful_Information/Shortcuts) seems to indicate: `<ctrl>`
+`<Home>` to go to the beginning of a project, and `<Ctrl>`+`<End>` to go to the end of a project ?  (I found the doc with a very simple google search: kdeenlive hotkeys )

If you indeed press that, check if your keyboard is not in some kind of numerical mode: many keyboards offer different mode for the numeric-pad keys (so that you can go to numerical mode and quickly enter many numbers in a spreadsheet, or go back to the other mode and quickly use the default usage of those same keys), and a `<Fn>`+`<some_key>` (or sometimes `<ctrl>`+`<Fn>`+`<some_key>`)  usually activates/deactivates that special mode.

Comment: I think you've mixed up sth. If I've understood the question correctly, the goal is to go to the clip's begin or end, not the project's begin/end.